# How do I fix: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I've been adding a saved HighScore system to my game but I've been getting this error:

Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type

This is my script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HighScoreDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text Display;
    public static int Score;
    private int HighScore;
    private int LateScore;

    void Start()
    {
        HighScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Display.text = (Score.ToString());

        // This is the error
        if (Score => HighScore)
        {
            HighScore = Score;
            Score = 0;
        }
        // ^This is the error^

        if (HighScore == LateScore)
        {

        }
        else
        {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", HighScore);
        }
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        LateScore = HighScore;
    }
}
```

Please help

Thx
Bren

Answer (score 3):

You need to >=, not => (flip the order)
You can only do >= for comparison because => is used for lambda expressions

Comment: I didn't know it was something that small. Thx